# MVC 3 multiple forms model passing to dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, partial-views

I'm quite new to MVC 3 and I'm stuck on an issue. The main layout look like this:

```
<body>
<div id="conteiner_body">
    <div id="conteiner_main">
        <div id="container_top">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("Basket"); }
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("MenuTop"); }
        </div>
        <div id="left_side_border">
            <div id="left_side">
                @{ Html.RenderPartial("SearchBox"); }
                @{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "LeftMenu"); }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("Footer"); }
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I have 3 forms on the page. First is in MenuTop view:

```
@model Models.LogOnModel
<div id="conteiner_menu_top">
    <div id="menu_top">
        <div id="login">
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

            @{
                using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account"))
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                    <input type="button" value="Registr" onclick="document.location.href = '/Account/Register'" />
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second is in SearchBox:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "SearchBox"))
{
<div id="search_box">
    <h2>Search</h2>
        <input name="searchWord" class="text" type="text" />
        <a href="rozsirene_vyhledavani">Advanced</a>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

and of course the form in RenderBody, which changes according to the context.
Problem is, when I post some form from RenderBody(), eg. Registration, I recieve following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Models.RegisterModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of
>   type 'Models.LogOnModel'.

I've tried to add to MenuTop and SearchBox their own dictionary:

```
Html.RenderPartial("MenuTop", new ViewDataDictionary(Models.LogOnModel))
Html.RenderPartial("SearchBox", new ViewDataDictionary(IEnumerable<Product>))
```

But in this case I get following error:

> CS0119: 'Models.LogOnModel' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Has anybody any idea, how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("MenuTop", new Models.LogOnModel());}
@{Html.RenderPartial("SearchBox", Enumerable.Empty<Product>());}
```